# Spring Cloud Stream message JSON conversion is not working

Tags: java, json, spring-cloud-stream

I followed my previous question [Spring Cloud Stream message from/to JSON conversion configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500759/spring-cloud-stream-message-from-to-json-conversion-configuration) and configured stream as described, yet, I can't make it work correctly.

My setup is as follows. I have two apps `A` and `B`. App `A` uses input channel `one`, output `two`. App `B` uses input `two`. Channel `two` is configured with content type `application/json`.

App A. Properties.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=one
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=default

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=two
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json
```

Listener method.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
public Dto handle(byte[] payload) throws IOException {
    final Dto dto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(payload, Dto.class);
    logger.info("{}", dto);
    dto.setId(dto.getId() + 1000);
    return dto;
}
```

App B. Properties.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=two
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=default
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json
```

Listener method.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)
public void handle(Dto dto) throws IOException {
    logger.info("DTO {}", dto);
}
```

When I manually send a message with proper JSON string to channel `one`, it is processed correctly and send to channel `two` as a JSON message (headers exactly the same as described in above mentioned question). After that, it's received on channel `two` by App B and exception is thrown: `Method handle(java.lang.String) cannot be found`

Of course when I create both methods, handling Dto and String as an input, it works, but always String method is invoked and have to deserialize the payload by myself.

Am I mistaken somewhere? How do I setup method with such signature: `public Dto handle(Dto incoming)`?

Comment: Why didn't you use `StreamListener` instead of `ServiceActivator` for your App B? I am not 100% sure but I think your problem could have be fixed using `StreamListener` instead of changing the `content-type` property.

Comment: At the time, such option wasn't available. But, yeah, that is a good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the content-type declaration of input of AppB to

`application/x-java-object;type=your.package.Dto`.

As it is specified in your question, of course you accept JSON strings only.

Comment: I don't need Java serialization. Take a look at the subject - I need JSON messages.

Comment: True, you would leave the content-type declaration of output of AppA to have JSON output, but AppB should be told via this content-type declaration that an according MessageConverter should convert the payload into a Dto object. The messages on the channel will be JSON, as one can see during debugging.

Comment: This actually works, thank you. Incredibly non-intuitive, considering how other Spring components work (AMQP or Rest).

Answer (score 0):

if use @StreamListener you don't have to use the answer way, but you have to remove (don't specify anything, otherwise it will be a json string):

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json
```

from AppB properties

source (old docs but still valid):
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.RELEASE/reference/html/contenttypemanagement.html#__literal_streamlistener_literal_and_message_conversion